# Parsing XML in R

Tags: xml, r

I am trying to download and organize some data from an XML file into R. I've looked at related questions and documentation, but most refer either to using the xml package parsing functions, which seem to not be able to figure out my data. So my two questions are 1) How do I get R to read the actual data into a data frame instead of the XML structure and mark up? and 2) Can I use XML structure information in the XML code to parse it in R?

This is what I am working with (and my failed attempts so far):

```
library("XML")
datahere = c("C:/.../R/feddata/data/")
setwd(datahere)

download.file("http://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/pomo/xml/v3_0/pomoXML.cfm?SHOWMORE=TRUE&date1=01/01/2009&date2=01/10/2009",paste(datahere,"feddata.xml",sep=""))

feddata = xmlInternalTreeParse("feddata.xml")
feddataset = xmlRoot(feddata)
names(feddata)
feddatanodeset = getNodeSet(feddata,"//DataSet/*")
feddatalist = xmlToList("feddata.xml")
feddatalist[2][1][1]
feddataDF = xmlToDataFrame(feddata)
feddata$doc$file$DataSet
feddata["doc"]["file"]["DataSet"]

feddataRoot = xmlRoot(feddata)
feddata2 = xmlSApply(feddata, function(x) xmlSApply(x,xmlValue))
feddata2 = xmlSApply(feddata$DataSet, function(x) xmlSApply(x,xmlValue))
```

Thoughts, suggestions, advice, and so on are greatly appreciated. If you know of another stack question or a tutorial or example somewhere I can use, that would also work, dont want to be redundant. Thanks!

Comment: What information do you try to extract from this xml document ?

Comment: I was just trying to get the data observations of the data as Scott and Ramnath did below. I'll try to be more specific in future questions, but I suppose thats one of the difficulties of being new at this stuff - not really knowing the right question to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
library(XML)
datahere = "~/"
setwd(datahere)
download.file("http://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/pomo/xml/v3_0/pomoXML.cfm?SHOWMORE=TRUE&date1=01/01/2009&date2=01/10/2009",paste(datahere,"feddata.xml",sep=""))
tt = xmlParse("feddata.xml")
out <- getNodeSet(tt, "//*[name()='out:issue']", fun=xmlToList)
df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, out))
head(df)

  confidentiality couponRate currency decimals inclusion maturityDate multiplier rate securityType status
1               F      4.750      USD        0      true   2011-01-18          0    P          FMC      A
2               F      4.500      USD        0      true   2011-02-15          0    P          FNM      A
3               F      4.625      USD        0      true   2011-02-18          0    P          FHL      A
4               F      3.250      USD        0      true   2011-02-25          0    P          FMC      A
5               F      5.500      USD        0      true   2011-03-15          0    P          FNM      A
6               F      5.625      USD        0      true   2011-03-15          0    P          FMC      A
      value
1  40000000
2   3000000
3   2000000
4         0
5  49000000
6 155000000
```

Comment: Ah, I tried this approach to but couldnt quite get the do.call(rbind) to work. This is helpful because I can see what I was doing wrong, which was primarily not understanding the organization of the xml file itself. Thanks!

Comment: Weird, `do.call` and `rbind` are in base R

Comment: oh yeah, I didnt mean the functions had a problem, I meant I was failing to use them correctly. More specifically, when trying to parse the XML, the information at the top of the file which is not data observations obviously cannot be rbound to the observations. Basically I couldnt really figure out how to navigate the XML properly, which you clarified with "//*[name()='out:issue']" step. I'm sure this is my lack of experience with XML structures, but its instructive to have your example. Thanks again!

Comment: ah, got it. have fun :)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using `plyr` and `XML`

```
library(XML)
doc <- xmlParse(
  "http://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/pomo/xml/v3_0/pomoXML.cfm?SHOWMORE=TRUE&date1=01/01/2009&date2=01/10/2009"  
)
doc_list <- xmlToList(doc)

library(plyr)
doc_issues <- ldply(doc_list$DataSet$Group, function(d){ 
  if ("issue" %in% names(d)){
    d$issue
  } else {
    NULL
  }
})
```

Comment: This does the trick too. I need to get more familiar with the plyr package, but I never really know when to think of it. Thanks a bunch!